# Angular6 auth0/angular2-jwt isTokenExpired function always return false if we valid Token

Tags: angular, angular6, angular2-jwt

I'm using auth0/angular2-jwt pakage for handling JWT Token Based authentication in Angular6 Application. if we gave valid token **isTokenExpired** function always returns false

The below code i have tried:

```
   localStorage.setItem('id_token', response['token']);
   const helper = new JwtHelperService();
   helper.isTokenExpired(localStorage.getItem('id_token')
```

And

```
constructor(
        private http: Http,
        private helper: JwtHelperService
    ) {
    }

public handleResponse(response: Response){
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', response['token']);  
 console.log(this.helper.isTokenExpired(localStorage.getItem('id_token')));

}
```

i have tried above two methods its always return **false**

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use { tokenNotExpired } 'angular2-jwt';
You will need following implementation:

Inside your app.module.ts

```
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';
. 
.
.
 @NgModule({

      providers: [
       .
       .
       { provide: 'tokenNotExpired', useValue: tokenNotExpired }, 
      ]

 })
```

and Inside your service where you need to check if toker is expired or not:

```
constructor( @Inject('tokenNotExpired') private tokenNotExpired)

isTokenExpired(idToken){
    return this.tokenNotExpired(idToken);
}
```

Comment: we are not using 'angular2-jwt' package please read question carefully

Comment: Could you please provide plunker for your problem ? This will help to solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

> Use tokenNotExpired('id_token')

The link below might help. Good luck.

https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/334#issuecomment-293968046

Comment: We are using Angular6 the above method used angular2-jwt old package